# Visual Studio 2010 Periodically Hangs for Several Seconds

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm having a problem where VS2010 Ultimate is freezing up every so often for several seconds before returning to normal operation. This happens several times during a session, and is obviously very annoying. I haven't been able to pin it down to any specific activity-- it seems to hang whenever I scroll around in a document, open/create a document, basically anything. Anyone else have this issue or know what might be the cause?

Comment: You're not connected to SourceSafe across the internet by any chance?  I find that VS does hang for a few seconds when it's updating source control statuses.  This isn't new with VS2010 tho - had it too with VS2008.

Comment: Try turning off stuff like intellisense. There are quite some options to be changed in the options dialogue that might improve performance. Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097421/performance-tips-for-making-visual-studio-2010-faster)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the issue was network related. One item in my solution was looking to a mapped network drive, which apparently didn't always respond fast enough.

Answer (score 12):

Incompatible add-ons or system configurations can cause Visual Studio issues (performance issue, error, etc).

Fortunately we can try to troubleshoot the issues by referring to the Visual Studio activity log.

Simply run the following command to run Visual Studio 2010 and log its all activities.

```
DevEnv.exe /log
```

The log file will be generated to:

**XP**

%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Visual Studio\10.0\ActivityLog.xml

**Vista & Windows 7**

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ActivityLog.xml

Once you run it, 2 files will be generated: ActivityLog.xml and ActivityLog.xsl

And when you open the ActivityLog.xml, it will contain something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The problem was solved by deleting the user options file called SolutionName.suo.

Somehow it had gotten very big and probably corrupted. You will only lose your breakpoints and open files as far as I know, but rename it to be safe.

Comment: This worked for me, nothing else did. I had 24 GB of RAM and Visual Studio was stalling with each character I typed, locking up, and crashing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I know people have had problems with computers that are older or don't have as much RAM. I know my use of VS 2010 ultimate can run to 500 MB's sometimes and if you don't have enough RAM, then it will hang for a little.

Comment: I thought it could be something like that too, except I have 8gb ram.

Comment: @Chris - Do you have a 64 bit system?

Comment: I have 6 gig of rams and have 4 gigs unused and I am getting the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I've had issues with VS2010 when debugging is running or if I'm opening files from a network drive.  I'm not sure as I currently don't have any team server repos connected, but if you do maybe the connection to the repo might be an issue as well.

Comment: I am indeed opening/editing files from a network drive, but that seems unlikely to be the issue as the files are all located within my network, which is running @ 100Mbit.

Comment: Well if you still encounter the same problems when only opening local files then you can definitely rule out the network drive.  Maybe try that if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for that problem was beyond the scope of my thinking. I found it on [this website](http://bernado-nguyen-hoan.com/2012/08/14/visual-studio-2010-freezes-periodically-for-a-few-seconds/), and it goes like:

> Launch Internet Explorer. Go to Internet Options, then Advanced tab. Under the Security group, untick “**Check for server certificate revocation**“. You may need to restart Visual Studio.

My scenario is that I have network drives with references mapped via VPN. That should have to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue with Visual Studio 2008. I have not thoroughly investigated the issue though.
Reading your post it seems the behavior at your PC is really annoying, but for me it's not that frequent.

One thing I noticed, the frequency at which this happens is dependent on the RAM size and time elapsed since last setup. I came to this conclusion seeing the performance of machines of my colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that my anti-virus software tends to lock down my entire system sometimes.  If you have an anti-virus application, you might try disabling it for a moment to see if it is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - that still happened after a /resetsettings, reinstall and using /safemode. For me, the issue was that Assembly Binding logging was turned on ago and I forgot to turn it off, it got to the stage where the log files concerned were >200MB and each append was taking ages...

Managed to find the issue with procmon from sysinternals. Suggest that anyone who comes across a similar issue tries procmon if none of the above solutions help.

Answer (score 0):

My `VS2010` would hang as well in a similar fashion.
`DevEnv.exe /log` would indicate it failed to load strings around the time it would hang.
Reinstalling `VS2010 SP1` and deinstalling `Resharper` to install `Resharper 7.1.3` solved the problem.