# Do different version of Visual Studio 2010 run faster or slower than each other?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I been wondering this since my VS2010 just seems to be dog slow and I have quite a speedy machine.

I am actually running my entire project on a RAM drive.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition and I am considering whether or not I should downgrade to a lesser version if it will run faster.

I don't really use the added features in the Ultimate SKU, but I don't want to uninstall and re-install if it isn't going to make a difference.

Anyone ever investigated this to find out if VS2010 Express, or VS2010 Pro is faster than VS2010 Ultimate?

Comment: Something is indeed wrong with your setup then :( VS2010 (albeit just Premium) runs very well here on my workstation -- and almost as well on my 3 year old laptop (Core Duo 2, 3GB RAM). All my machines have SSD, but if you say you are using a "RAM drive" then that *shouldn't* be a factor...

Comment: Visual Studio is slow by default! :D

Comment: Using a RAM drive is a very bad idea.  It consumes RAM that could be put to a better use.  Like the many megabytes of code that makes VS tick.  And the file system cache.  Windows can be smart about what should be kept in that cache.  You stop it from making good decisions.  Get ahead by defragging your drive, when is the last time you did that?

Comment: I am using a 3 GB RAM drive on a PC that has 16 GB of total RAM so that is not relevant.  Using a RAM drive is the fastest possible disk access.

Comment: There seems to be numerous complaints about sluggishness in vs2010 at the user voice channel (http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio).  Most seem to point the finger at the WPF overhaul.  For me I noticed an improvement after installing SP1, but still have the occasional slow down.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently upgraded my solutions to VS2010 and I am also using the ultimate version. But I didn't notice such a slowness. I think VS2010 is performing better than 2005 even though it consumes some more RAM. I've got a 8GB ram though and I think it will be some what slower if your RAM is below 4GB. Sometimes the addins (if you have installed any) can make the IDE slower. So upgrade them to VS2010 versions or disable them and see whether there is any difference...

For you it may be worth to have a look into this, [Performance tips for making Visual Studio 2010 faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097421/performance-tips-for-making-visual-studio-2010-faster).

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, the different SKUs of Visual Studio are actually the same product with different components, features, or add-ins enabled or disabled. As a result, all of them should run pretty much the same. If you are experiencing such poor performance you could reinstall but before you do that try deleting any .suo files (you may have to show hidden files to see them). In my experience 9.5 out of 10 times when Visual Studio (any version) starts misbehaving it is due to the .suo file.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: I believe the extra features of the higher level SKU don't impact performance unless they are actually used.  Since you already said you rarely use them, there should be little difference between versions

It might help to [Reset your settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075.aspx)

I had a similar experience with Visual Studio 2010.  I had just purchased a new laptop (i7-2720QM, 8 Gb RAM). Since I had my work environment setup the way I liked (Font / Syntax highlighting colors, etc) I exported my settings at work, and imported them at home.

Everything was slow, so I uninstalled / reinstalled.  Everything was fast.  Once I imported the settings again, everything was slow again.

I caught on, and opened up the exported settings file in a text editor.  Turns out one of the settings referenced a UNC path that, of course, didn't exist on my home network.

So every time I built my code (among other times) it locked up until it timed out.

If your system is fast, and it you think it should have enough horsepower for Visual Studio, you are probably right.  But RAM / CPU / Disk drive are not the only things that can impact your Visual Studio speed.

Also, remember VS2010 uses WPF.  Make sure your video card drivers are up to date.  If you need to you can also [disable Hardware acceleration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx)